# When I extract keywords from e-mails to Excel, the keywords in a single e-mail count as two

Tags: excel, powershell, outlook

```
# Init le module Outlook

Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook


# Init une nouvelle instance Outlook

$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application


# Récupère la boîte de réception

$Inbox = $Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)


# Défini le mot-clé à rechercher

$Bascules = "Bascule OK"


# Init le compteur des bascules

$CompteurBasc = 0


# Parcours les mails non lus dans la boîte de réception

$Inbox.Items | Where-Object { $_.UnRead -eq $true } | ForEach-Object {

    if ($_ -is [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem]) {


        # Vérifie si le courriel contient le mot-clé
        
        if ($_.Body -like "*$Bascules*") {

            $CompteurBasc++
        }

        Write-Host $_.Body
    }
}   


# Définit le chemin du fichier Excel de destination

$CheminFichierExcel = "D:\PowerShell\GestionMails\donnees.xlsx"


# Crée un objet Excel

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

# Ouvre le fichier Excel

$Classeur = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($CheminFichierExcel)


# Sélectionne la feuille de calcul (par défaut, la première feuille est sélectionnée)

$Feuille = $Classeur.Sheets.Item(1)


# Écrit le résultat du compteur dans la feuille Excel

$Feuille.Cells.Item(1, 1) = "Bascules"
$Feuille.Cells.Item(1, 2) = $CompteurBasc


# Lit la valeur existante dans la cellule B1 (où les valeurs sont stockées)

$ValeurExistante = $Feuille.Range("B1").Value()


# Vérifie si la valeur existante est null ou vide, sinon, convertit en nombre

if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ValeurExistante)) {

    $ValeurExistante = 0

} else {

    # Convertit en chaîne, puis en double

    $ValeurExistante = [double]([string]$ValeurExistante)
}


# Ajoute le compteur actuel à la valeur existante

$NouvelleValeur = $ValeurExistante + $CompteurBasc


# Écrit la nouvelle valeur (la somme) dans la cellule B1

$Feuille.Range("B1").Value() = $NouvelleValeur


# Enregistre le fichier Excel

$Classeur.Save()

$Excel.Quit()

$Outlook.Quit()


# Libère la mémoire

[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()


# Quitte le script proprement

exit
```

I want to extract keywords to an Excel file from Outlook emails. It works, except that when I extract a keyword from an e-mail, it counts as 2 when it's alone. I hope I've made myself clear. I just want to make "Toggle OK" count as 1 and not as 2.

Can you help me please?

I thought it might be because "Bascule OK" had 2 words, so I tried "Bascule" but the problem was the same. I'm sure it's nothing, but I've been stuck for a while, so if you have any idea.

Comment: Where in your script is it throwing an error and what's the exact error text?

Comment: That's a lot of incidental code and there's no explanation for your symptom in the relevant part of your code; as an aside: you can simplify to: `$CompteurBasc = ($Inbox.Items | Where-Object { $_ -is [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem] -and $_.UnRead -and $_.Body -like "*$Bascules*" }).Count`

Comment: I wonder if each message has a plain-text and a MIME encoded version where both contain the match phrase? Also, please try `if ($_.Body -match $Bascules)`.

Comment: @jeremywat there are no errors, the script works, it just doesn't return the right data.

Comment: @lit I already tried to use -match instead of -like, in the end it doesn't change the data at all. It may be more efficient, however

Answer (score 0):

Your code is extremely inefficient. The line

```
$Inbox.Items | Where-Object { $_.UnRead -eq $true } | ForEach-Object {
```

loops through **all** item in the Inbox, which can contain thousands of messages. Replace  `$Inbox.Items` with `$Inbox.Items.Restrict("[Unread]=true")`

As for why the counter is 2, you really need to step through your code to make sure you only hit a single item, not two.